# RTK Query - Error undefined for 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, rtk-query, http-status-code-400

Sorry if this is a badly formed question, this is my first time asking!

What is the best way to catch and handle errors when using RTK Query hooks? I would like to be able to handle different statuses - especially 400, in order to determine if the user has a login.

I am using JSON-server and I have created an RTK Query authAPiSlice that works fine when I attempt to log in a user that exists in the db.json file. Testing the login with details for a user that doesn't exist does error but both the error and status returned are 'undefined'.

This is my authApi.ts file:

```
export const authApiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "authApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:3333/login" }),
  tagTypes: ['User'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    loginUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (newUser: NewUser) => ({
        url: ``,
        method: "POST",
        body: newUser,
        // Getting the result as text makes it easier to parse into JSON
        responseHandler: (response) => response.text(),
        // responseHandler: (response) => response.json(),
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["User"],
      // transformResponse: (response: {data: User}) =>
      //   response.user,
    }),
  }),
});
```

This is the function I am calling from the handleSubmit method to attempt the login and deal with errors:

```
 const [loginUser, { data: loginResult, status, error, isError, isLoading }] = useLoginUserMutation();
  const attemptLogin = (user: NewUser): JSX.Element => {
    // Attempt login using email and password
    loginUser(user);

    // Deal with any API related issues
    if (isLoading) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }
    if (isError || !loginResult || error) {

      const errorString = JSON.stringify(error);
      const statusString = JSON.stringify(status);
      const resString = JSON.stringify(loginResult);
      alert(`Login failed - error = ${errorString} 
                        status = ${statusString}
                        result = ${resString}`);
      console.error(`Login failed - Error = ${error}`);
      return <h1>Unsuccessful login</h1>;
    } else {
      alert("Login successful");
      console.log(loginResult);
      storeUserNames();
      return <h1></h1>;
    };
```

Calling it as follows:

```
const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user: NewUser = {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password
    };
    attemptLogin(user);
  };
```

Sorry, the code is a bit messy, as I have just been trying different ways to get access to the error so that I can stop it from causing a problem. I have tried a try {} catch {} previously but that doesn't seem to be aligned with how RTK Query hooks are set up.

When I try the same request on Postman the status comes back as 400 and the body as "cannot find user" and this is also shown in the console as an error from the debugger.

The console log output reads:

```
index.tsx:33 Login failed - Error = undefined
attemptLogin    @   index.tsx:33
handleSubmit    @   index.tsx:64
```

status comes back as 'uninitialized' and the error as 'undefined'.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatched query actions work a lot like regular asynchronous actions, e.g. thunks.

Given login mutation hook:

```js
const [
  loginUser,
  { data: loginResult, status, error, isError, isLoading }
] = useLoginUserMutation();
```

The login component will call the trigger function and can `await` for it to complete.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const user: NewUser = {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password
    };
    const data = await loginUser(user).unwrap();

    // login successful, do what you need, e.g. navigate to a user dashboard, etc
  } catch(error) {
    // login failed
    // handle any thrown exceptions or rejected Promises
  }
};
```

The rest of the UI can use the mutation result metadata to handle rendering errors, loading indicators, etc.

```
...

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError || !loginResult || error) {
    const errorString = JSON.stringify(error);
    const statusString = JSON.stringify(status);
    const resString = JSON.stringify(loginResult);

    alert(`
      Login failed - error = ${errorString} 
      status = ${statusString}
      result = ${resString}
    `);

    console.error(`Login failed - Error = ${error}`);
  } else {
    alert("Login successful");
    console.log(loginResult);
    storeUserNames();
  }
}, [isError, error, loginResult]);

...

if (isLoading) {
  return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
}

if (isError || !loginResult || error) {
  return <h1>Unsuccessful login</h1>;
} else {
  return <h1></h1>;
};

...
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this and your reply! 
Just wondering, if data is unpacked here:

const [
  loginUser,
  { data: loginResult, status, error, isError, isLoading }
] = useLoginUserMutation();

Does it still need to be assigned here:

 const data = await loginUser(user).unwrap();

Comment: @Hez I don't believe so, IIRC `data` returned from the trigger function is *just* the response data, sans all the query metadata the hook also provides. See [useMutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#signature-1) signature, specifically the `UseMutationTrigger` type declaration, the `unwrap` function is a "A method to unwrap the mutation call and provide the ***raw response/error***" (emphasis is mine).

Comment: That makes sense I guess. I am going to have to look at this again at a later date unfortunately as I am up against it and just need to get the backend and frontend talking. Going back to axios to make things simpler for now... (fingers crossed)